# Flags in database - Sensible way of keeping track

Tags: sql, database, linux, postgresql, debian

I am trying to design my first database and I have found that I have quite a few different "flags" that I want to keep of in the database:

```
Active      # Shows whether the item submission has been completed
Indexed     # Shows whether the item has been indexed
Reminded        # Shows whether the “expiring email” has been sent to the user
Error       # Shows whether there is an error with the submission
Confirmation    # Shows whether the confirmation email has been sent
```

Other than just having a Boolean field for these, is there a clever way of storing these details? I was wondering if I had these under a status group in the database with an ID for every connotation (32) and just link to that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless there is some reason to do otherwise, I'd recommend simply adding those five boolean (or bit) columns to the item table.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how immutable the list of connotations is.

If there are just the five you mentioned then just add five flag columns. If the list of possible connotations could change in the future, it might be safer to have a separate table with a list of connotations that currently apply to each row in the main table, with a one-to-many relationship.

Answer (score 0):

Consider:

```
Table: Vehicle
ID
Type
Doors
Color

Table: Type_Categories
ID
Name

Table: Types
TypeID
CategoryID
Value
DataType
```

This way reuse of type can occur in other places as needed.  However this assumes non-boolean "Flags" if all flags are truly boolean...  Id stick w/ putting them in the table.  But I always hated boolean values.  I preferred time stamps so I know when the flag was set not just that it was set.  if the timestamp is null, then it's not been set.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience the status columns frequently evolve to more than two states. So I would use a `smallint` for each status for convenience and simplicity.

But if your aim is to save space then you can save all the statuses in a single `smallint` using casts to and from `bit` to manipulate the statuses individually or as a whole.

```
create table t (status smallint);
```

To save `10010` then cast it to smallint:

```
insert into t (status) values (b'10010'::int::smallint);
```

List all statuses:

```
select status::int::bit(5) from t;
 status 
--------
 10010
```

To set the 3rd status use the `bitwise or`:

```
update t set status = (status::integer::bit(5) | b'00100')::integer::smallint;
select status::int::bit(5) from t;
 status 
--------
 10110
```

To unset that status use the `bitwise and`:

```
update t set status = (status::integer::bit(5) & b'11011')::integer::smallint;
select status::int::bit(5) from t;
 status 
--------
 10010
```

To retrieve the lines with the 3rd status set:

```
select status
from t
where substring(status::integer::bit(5) from 3 for 1) = '1'
```

You could write functions to simplify the conversions.

Answer (score 0):

If they are "just" flags, store them as boolean-type columns on the table.

I'd recommend against Clodoaldo's solution unless space is REALLY tight - see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5708239/when-is-it-better-to-store-flags-as-a-bitmask-rather-than-using-an-associative-t/5708369#5708369) question.

It looks like the columns you mention have "business importance" - i.e. it may not be enough to store "Indexed", but also the date on which the item was indexed. It may be necessary to limit combinations of states, or impose rules on the sequencing (you can't go to complete whilst being in error state). In that case, you may want to implement an "item_status" table to store history etc.

In this case, your schema would be something like this:

```
ITEM
---------
item_id
....

STATUS
---------
status_id
description

ITEM_STATUS
--------------
item_id
status_id
date
```

Every time an item changes status, you insert a new row into the ITEM_STATUS table; the current status is the row with the latest date for that item.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more about this, do I have a item_status table with ID which links up to the main "item" and item status would have dated fields for "indexed" to show when it was completed?

Comment: I've included a sample schema