# bitwise operation in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, bitwise-operators, bitwise-and

please can someone help me to understand this condition `val1 & 11 = 0`

```
SELECT val FROM table WHERE val1 & 11 = 0
```

available for more information.
Thanks a lot

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does "&" means in this sql where clause?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15289955/what-does-means-in-this-sql-where-clause)

Comment: What about yh operation don't you understand here so we can try to fill in your blanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`11` is `1011` in base 2. The code selects rows where 1st, 2nd and 4th bits are 0. I.e. it will match where val1 in 0, 4, 16, 20, 32, 36, 48, ...