# What type of technique should I use for best overall speed when performing status comparisons for permissions/authorizations?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, performance, asp.net-mvc-5

MVC5 vb.net SQL

The application will employ permissions for authorization rather than roles.  Permissions will be evaluated for basic CRUD (Create, Read, Update, Delete).  Permissions for each user will be stored in an SQL database.  So, to deal with CRUD, there will be 4 discrete data to be stored, retrieved and processed.

Since permissions are checked for almost all methods called, permissions will be checked frequently using an attribute filter, and it would seem overall speed needs to be minded for this. I'm asking for help considering all the ramifications from how the data is stored and retrieved in the SQL database to the overall speed cost depending on the technique employed.

The following techniques come to mind for storing the permission data: `Boolean`, `Bitwise`, `Characters in a string`.  I presume `bitwise` would be fastest followed by `Boolean`, and `Characters in a string` would be costly.  But sometimes we don't understand the other implications of what seems to be a simple decision.

So these are the questions I'm asking myself, but I don't have the experience to know the answers:

**Bitwise.** All 4 CRUD data are encoded into a single data item so database operations would seem to be quickest.  I'm assuming `bitwise` evaluation is also fastest, but maybe not.  Are there hidden costs to `bitwise` comparisons?  What is the best datatype for using `bitwise`?

**Boolean.**  `Boolean` would require 4 data items, but that doesn't seem like it would be a big penalty for database operations.  `Boolean` comparisons seem like they would be fastest for comparison because they are true/false compared to the need for a mask when using `bitwise`.

**Characters in a string.**  This would seem the worst possible choice, but I only ask because there may be issues I'm unaware of when it comes to selecting a character from a string and testing it.  Storage would be 4 characters in a field, but I don't know if that's a penalty to worry about regarding database operations.  Testing would check an indexed location in the string, but does that, in fact, mean it would be a big penalty?

While I assume for best speed I need to load a user's permissions into memory while they are logged in, this would seem to be a 'wash' compared to the processing considerations I've asked about above.

Please add any other considerations I've not mentioned.

Comment: Please tag your database engine.

Comment: Does this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5708239/when-is-it-better-to-store-flags-as-a-bitmask-rather-than-using-an-associative-t/5708369#5708369 help?

Comment: Tagged, & VERY helpful SO post regarding bitwise. I was concerned the expressive aspect shouldn't be considered but your answer relieved that concern.  I'm using a denormalized table consistent with one other answer in that question; each user's records can be quickly loaded at log in.  So my question is now between Boolean and characters in a string. Boolean would require 4 data to be available for the attribute processing, a string indexed to the CRUD bit under test requires only one data to be passed.  Thoughts?

Comment: I don't think it will make a big performance difference; once you've loaded the permissions into memory, the rest is probably too fast to measure. Personally, I find the booleans most expressive...

Comment: Sql Server combines bit columns into a byte for storage for up to 8 columns. So, I guess Sql Server is using a bitmask internally.